# Variable size square table command

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I'm trying to make a command that creates a square table with equal elements. The table size needs to be user defined.
Something like this:

```latex
\tabelax{<size>}{<element>}
```

Example:

```latex
\tabelax{3}{a}
```

will give:

[image: result]

I'm trying the following code:

```latex
\newcounter{coluna}  % número de colunas
\newcounter{linha}  % número de linhas

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\tabelax}[2]{   
    \setcounter{coluna}{0}
    \setcounter{linha}{0}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|
        \setcounter{coluna}{0}
        \@whilenum\value{coluna}<#1\do{
            c|\stepcounter{coluna}}
        }%
    \hline
    \setcounter{linha}{0}
    \@whilenum\value{linha}<#1\do{
        #2\setcounter{coluna}{0}
        \@whilenum\value{coluna}<#1\do{ 
            & #2 \stepcounter{coluna}
        }\\\hline\stepcounter{linha}
    }
        
    \end{tabular}

}
\makeatother
```

which generates the following error:

```
Package array:  Illegal pream-token (\@nil): `c' used.
LaTeX
Package array: Empty preamble: `l' used.
LaTeX
Only one # is allowed per tab.
\@preamble ...mpdima width\z@ \unhbox \z@ \@sharp 
LaTeX
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...a width\z@ \unhbox \z@ \endtemplate 
LaTeX
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might exploit the `youngtab` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tabelax}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of lines, #2 = symbol
  \felipe_tabelax:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__felipe_tabelax_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \felipe_tabelax:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__felipe_tabelax_tl { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__felipe_tabelax_tl { , \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   }
  \__felipe_tabelax_make:V \l__felipe_tabelax
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__felipe_tabelax_make:n
 {
  \young(#1)
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__felipe_tabelax_make:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tabelax{3}{a} \tabelax{1}{b} \tabelax{4}{c}

\end{document}
```

In the first example, the code builds a token list consisting of

```
aaa,aaa,aaa
```

and passes it to `\young`. See the package documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix`  provides several commands in order to compose automatically matrices of variable size from a
general pattern.

These commands take in two mandatory arguments. The first is the format of the matrix, with the
syntax `r-c` where `r` is the number of rows and `c` the number of columns. The second argument is the
pattern (it’s a list of tokens which are inserted in each cell of the constructed matrix).

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\AutoNiceMatrix{3-3}{\color{red}a}$

\bigskip

$\AutoNiceMatrix{1-1}{\fbox{b}}$

\bigskip

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{-0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt} 

$\AutoNiceMatrix{4-4}{\fbox{c}}$

\bigskip

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

$\pAutoNiceMatrix{3-7}{\alpha_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}}$   
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use `\halign` table (i.e tabular environment in LaTeX), boxes and `\loop` macro are sufficient:

```
\newcount \tableN 
\def\tableax#1#2{\tableN=#1\vbox{\hrule \relax
   \loop \tableR{#1}{#2}
         \hrule
         \advance\tableN by-1
         \ifnum\tableN>0 \repeat
}}
\def\tableR#1#2{\hbox{\tableN=#1\vrule height.85em depth.35em \relax
   \loop \hbox to1.2em{\hss#2\hss}\vrule
         \advance\tableN by-1
         \ifnum\tableN>0 \repeat
}}

test: \tableax{3}{a}
```

Why we need only single counter? Because rows are typeset in the TeX group (in `\hbox{}`) and we can borrow the same counter for inner loop here.